# Using SIGUSR signals to synchronise multiple child processes in order of their PIDs

Tags: c, synchronization, signals, system-calls

Given an input `n`, we need to create `n` processes such that process `i` is the parent of process `i+1`. Each process should print it's `pid` `1000` times, each time waiting for every other process to print their `pid`. The processes should print their `pid` in an increasing order.

Example:

```
n = 4
```

Output:

```
1820 1823 1876 1954
.
.1000 times
.
1820 1823 1876 1954
```

where 1820, 1823, 1876 and 1954 are process IDs.
Although I can have a rough idea on how to execute each process alternatively using `SIGUSR1` and `wait()` signals, what I am unable to figure out is considering child and parent ids are random, how can it be ensured that the order in which they execute is according to the process IDs.

Comment: Each parent knows when it prints and knows the pid of its child.

Comment: But isn't it possible that pid of child is smaller than pid of parent? @stark

Comment: Is it possible that whoever assigned this problem is really asking, "have each process in an ancestry chain print its PID, then the next, then the next ... repeating 1000 times?"  On most systems, most of the time, PIDs in a process ancestry chain would happen to be ascending.  You're right that PID assignment may be truly random (OpenBSD, IIRC) or may wrap around.